# Using jQuery to load content and appendTo an element

Tags: jquery, html, css, appendto

I want to use ajax to load some HTML, and then place it as the last child of a `<div>`.

`$('div').load('extra-stuff.php');` will replace all content of the div. `appendTo()` sounds promising, but now what is the most efficient jQuery AJAX function to use, and how can it work with `appendTo`?

Comment: You're looking for `$.get()`. Read the documentation, play around with it and come back when you have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [`jQuery.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
$.get('extra-stuff.php', function(data){
    $('div').append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append using load like this:

```
jQuery('#AppendToMe').append( jQuery('<div>').load(...) );
```